# CSS chat layout not working

Tags: css

Hello I am trying to make an online chat application.

I have the html:

```
<body>
    <table align="center" width="80%">
        <tbody class="scroll">
            <!--All of the chat-->
        </tbody>

        <tbody class="formheight" style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form style="width:100%" action="Write-to.php" method="post">
                        <input autocomplete="off" name="txt" type="text" id="usermsg" style="font-size:2.4vw;" value="" />
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

And the css:

```
html, body
{
  height: 100%;
  max-height:100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
table
{
  height: 100%;
}
tbody {
    overflow: auto;
    width:100%;
}
thead > tr, tbody{
    display:block;
    }
```

---

I want the 2nd `tbody` (The one that contains the `form`) to lie at the bottom of the page and the first to fill the rest of the page upwards.

---

Currently I am having to use jquery to (kind of) do what I want. *Currently the form is half hidden*. I would rather do this all with CSS so that it works better with mobile devices.
How could I do that?

Jquery:

```
var heighty = $(window).height();
var height = $('.formheight').height();
$(".scroll").css("height", heighty - height + "px");
```

---

I also can't for the life of me get the `form text input` to be 100% width?

---

## Please see [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FwTbz/1/)

---

### I am also very open to another way of laying out this chat app all together!

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible in CSS, but would be very difficult to get working across all browsers. Instead, here is my recommendation:

- Create an element that fills up 100% height with a bottom padding set to X px.
- Create an element with `position:fixed` and a height of X px.
- <strike>Give the latter element a `z-index:2` and the former a `z-index:1`.</strike> z-index doesn't need to be assigned manually, elements further down in source code automatically have a higher priority and are displayed over previous elements (if they overlay visually).

If you want, you could use a different unit. Percents are very easy because you can have them add up to 100%, so no need for a margin. Of course each has its respective drawbacks, but in my experience what I've described generally has good compatibility and displays comparably on all devices. You could even use CSS `@media` queries to change the height, *X*, for different devices.

Comment: I have tried [this](http://jsfiddle.net/5f6yZ/) but no luck! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's basically something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/5f6yZ/9/). z-index isn't actually important, it's automatically assigned to elements based on where they are in the source. An item will overlay another if it appears further down in source code (these elements are added to the DOM later).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something what we call a "Sticky Footer", In your case, your second body goes in the sticky footer. Have a look at this http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/ or this http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/ for the `css+html` for a sticky footer